# El nombre del dropdown no cambia cuando hago una seleccion

Tags: bootstrap, angular

Resulta que cuando despliego el dropdown y selecciono una de las opciones el botón no cambia.

Me refiero a que tengo un imput-group con dos casillas de texto y un dropdown. En el "placeholder" del boton "dropdown" (el que se despliega en cascada) dice "Tipo" y esperaría que al desplegarlo y seleccionar alguna de las opciones dadas (Entrada y Salida) el "placeholder" del boton cambiara de "Tipo" a "Entrada" o "Salida" dependiendo de lo que el usuario escoja.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Abacus</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <input #toFocus [(ngModel)]="concepto" placeholder="concepto" type="text" class="form-control" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
  <input [(ngModel)]="valor" type="text" placeholder="monto" class="form-control"(keypress)="enter($event.keyCode, toFocus)" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <option class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Tipo
    </option>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="tipoDeMovimiento('entrada')">Entrada</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="tipoDeMovimiento('salida')">Salida</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-2" (click)="crear()" >Agregar</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui dejo el codigo que estoy usando actualmente.

Tipo
    
    
      Entrada
      Salida
    
  



  Agregar

Mil gracias!!!

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! deberias agregar a tu pregunta una forma de reproducir tu problema, si no es imposible ayudarte. usa el boton [edit] y agrega el codigo que te trae problemas

Comment: Como @gbianchi te inidica, necesitamos más informacion para poder ayudarte. muestranos la parte del código que es relevante para la pregunta y qué cosas has intentado.

Comment: No se como mas exponer mi dificultad. Quizás las pocas horas que tengo de experiencia no me están ayudando.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un option como place holder:

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona Rol</option>
```